# Why a function is Lipschitz in a neighborhood of $x_0$, if $f$ has derivative at $x_0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ is continuously differentiable in its domain.Take $x_{0}$ in $R^n$.can we conclude that for any positive real number $M$, there is an open ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $e$ ($e>0$), i.e. the set $B=\{x\,|\,\lvert x-x_0\rvert<e\}$, s.t. for any $x,y$ in $B$, $$\lvert Df(x)-Df(y)\rvert<M\lvert x-y\rvert.$$

PS: $x,y$ are vectors ,and $[Df(x)]$ is the Jacobi matrix of $f$ at $x$. The absolute value of a matrix $A$ ($m\times n$) is the square root of the sum of the squares of all its elements, i.e. $$|A|=\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+..+a_{1n}^2+…+a_{m1}^2+..+a_{mn}^2}$$

Comment: Are you sure you want $|Df(x)-Df(y)|<M|x-y|$ instead of $|f(x)-f(y)<M|x-y|$?

Comment: absolutely not. Differentiability at one point alone doesn't guarantee differentiability in a neighborhood of that point. Heck, it doesn't even guarantee continuity in a neighorhood of that points, let alone Lipschitz continuity. There are standard counterexamples in the case $n=m=1$. What is true is if the function is differentiable on a say convex open set (e.g. an open ball) with bounded derivative, then it is Lipschitz continuous (consequence of mean-value inequality).

Comment: @peek-a-boo You’re right,I need to add some restrictions on f.

Comment: @student91 yes,It’s about the derivative of f.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after the edit, it is still false. Let $w:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a continuous, nowhere differentiable function (e.g the famous Weierstrass function), and $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\int_0^xw(t)\,dt$. Then, $f$ is $C^1$, with $f'=w$. But, $f'$ is not locally Lipschitz, because if it was, then by Rademacher's theorem, $f'=w$ would have to be differentiable a.e, but this contradicts our hypothesis that $w$ is nowhere differentiable. I wouldn't be surprised if there are simpler counterexamples, but this is a quick one.

p.s. the Lipschitz condition should be written with a weak inequality $\leq$, or you should say "for all distinct $x,y$".